# VUE When I used $router.push.() to jump other page,back button will jump to the last page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

There is a HTML page in my vue project
[image: time list]

when I press "+" button,it will jump to this page
[image: Timing]

This page is for user to timing,and the last page is time list.

Now,I`m doing timing in TimingPage and press "保存"(save),it will going to TimeList page,and print time witch I have set.

and than,I press the "Native" back button(!!!this native button is not the back button in my page,it`s button in the browser or your smartphone!!!),it will going to Timing page instead of home page!

Just like when you click the back button while browsing, it will jump to the page you just visited instead of the previous page.

there is my code:

```
<van-nav-bar
  :title="$t('socketPage.addTiming')"
  :left-text="$t('socketPage.cancel')"
  :right-text="$t('socketPage.save')"
  @click-left="$router.push('/timeList')"
  @click-right="saveTime();$router.push('/timeList')"
></van-nav-bar>
```

I used $router.push.() to jump.

excuse my poor english .

Answer (score 2):

If I unnderstand you clearly, then the issue is with how you are routing. Using `$router.push()` will always add a route to the routing stack so going back will take you to the previous page on the stack.

To solve this, use the `$router.replace()` or `$router.pop()` method instead in the TimingPage

To further understand the difference, check [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) out.

HTH

Comment: you save my life

Comment: Welcome. I meant `$router.back()` not `$router.pop()` though

Comment: I thought so too because the replace method might require you to press the back twice